# XSL FO inline-container remove margins and align next to each other

Tags: pdf, xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

First of all: i use Apache Formatting Objects Processor 2.3 for generating PDF files

There are two questions that build on each other, so I wanted to put them together in one post.

I have a `.fo` file in which i created labeled text blocks where a title is in a left bounded block and the content text in a right bounded block.

First i implemented that with `fo:table` elements, but for reasons that are not important here, i need to go with `fo:inline-container` instead.

So this is a simplified `.fo` file of mine:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fo:root
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
    xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">

    <fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:simple-page-master master-name="Inhalt-Seiten" page-height="29.7cm" page-width="21cm" margin-top="1.5cm" margin-bottom="1.5cm" margin-left="2cm" margin-right="1.5cm">
            <fo:region-body margin-top="3.5cm" margin-bottom="1.25cm" margin-left="1cm" margin-right="1cm"/>
            <fo:region-before region-name="MAIN-EVEN-header" extent="3.5cm"/>
            <fo:region-after extent="1.25cm"/>
            <fo:region-start region-name="MAIN-EVEN-left" extent="1cm"/>
            <fo:region-end extent="1cm"/>
        </fo:simple-page-master>
    </fo:layout-master-set>
    <fo:page-sequence master-reference="Inhalt-Seiten">
        <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
            <fo:block background-color="green">
                <fo:inline-container inline-progression-dimension="20%" vertical-align="top" background-color="yellow">
                    <fo:block>
                        Test
                    </fo:block>
                </fo:inline-container>
                <fo:inline-container inline-progression-dimension="80%" vertical-align="top" background-color="red">
                    <fo:block>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
                    </fo:block>
                </fo:inline-container>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:flow>
    </fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
```

That creates the following output:

[image: PDFOutput]

## Question 1 - Alignment

So first of all: why are they not aligned next to each other?
I could set the yellow `inline-progression-dimension` to `19%` and the red `inline-progression-dimension` to `79%` but this leads to gaps that I do not want (see picture).

[image: newpercentages]

## Question 2 - Top and bottom margins

As you can see, the green block sticks out a little at the top and bottom. Is there any way to prevent this? I have now already tried to set the margins and paddings to 0 but without success

Comment: Why not use `fo:list-block`, et al. (See https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#fo_list-block)

Comment: isnt `fo:list-block` for stacking `fo:block` elements vertically and not horizontally?

Comment: Ah sorry maybe I should read before I write. I will start a try with `fo:list-block`

Comment: Did you check if FOP supports fo:inline-container?

Comment: `fo:list-block` did the magic!!! Thanks

Comment: @TonyGraham: how about putting that as an answer?

Comment: Added the answer!

Comment: You can also accept your own answer for the sake of completeness.

Comment: Nope... need to wait 24 hours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using a `fo:list-block` instead of `fo:inline-container`.

Thanks to [@Tony Graham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4092205/tony-graham)

```xml
<fo:block background-color="green">
    <fo:list-block provisional-label-separation="0pt" provisional-distance-between-starts="20%">
        <fo:list-item>
            <fo:list-item-label end-indent="label-end()">
                <fo:block background-color="yellow">
                    Test
                </fo:block>
            </fo:list-item-label>
            <fo:list-item-body start-indent="body-start()">
                <fo:block background-color="red">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
                </fo:block>
            </fo:list-item-body>
        </fo:list-item>
    </fo:list-block>
</fo:block>
```

Creates the desired output with no margins and perfectly aligned:

[image: output]